# DocuSign Rest API - limit the connect failure log

Tags: rest, logging, connect, docusignapi

Is there a parameter one can pass to limit the size of retrieved connect failures? The SOAP API has 2 date parameters one can pass I don't see similar option in REST API

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no unfortunately.